# API with parameter and "+" sign

Tags: javascript, get

After an hour of SO, and trying many things I can not figure out how to pass another argument through with the following API:

```
.get("http://websitenamehere.php?id="+alpha)
```

`alpha` is a parameter that I get with my function that I want to pass through - and it works fine. Now I want to extend this code to pass through more than one parameter (lets call them `bravo` and `charlie`)

I have tried:

```
.get("http://websitenamehere.php?id="+alpha+bravo+charlie)  //puts everything together
.get("http://websitenamehere.php?id=,id2="+alpha,bravo)  //nada
.get("http://websitenamehere.php?id=alpha,id2=bravo")   //zero
.get("http://websitenamehere.php?id="+alpha,"id2="+bravo)  //nope
```

I have so far found out that this can look like php code, which it is not. It is in JS.

Comment: If they are different get values, you'd need something like `?id="+alpha+"&id2="+bravo` - it all depends on how it's treated in the receiving script

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know where is the documentation for this? If you make this an answer I can mark it correct.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any proper documentation on it. It's just how GET values are sent though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build a valid URL with multiple GET-parameters, you need to separate them with `&` and give each parameter a name. In your particular case, it'd be

```
"...?id="+alpha+"&id2="+bravo
//   ^             ^
// first name      second name
```

Which would build a string such as

```
...?id=foo&id2=bar
```

Where `id` and `id2` are the names of each parameter, and `&` indicates that a new name is about to be defined. Each name gets its value through the equality-sign, `=`.

Those can now be fetched in PHP through `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['id2']`.

Answer (score 0):

use `http_build_query`. Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

`.get("http://websitenamehere.php?".http_build_query(['id'=>alpha,'id2'=>'bravo']))`

For Javascript

`.get("http://websitenamehere.php?id="+alpha+"&id2=bravo")`

use `&` to separate the parameters

Comment: I do not believe OP's code is in PHP as they are using the javascript concatenation operator (`+`) and not PHP's concatenation operator (`.`)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have added that I am struggling on the JS side, not on the php side.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use this:

```
.get("http://websitenamehere.php?id[]="+alpha+"&id[]="+bravo+"&id[]="+charlie)
```

This will result in sending array of IDs to server